# Eclipse on Windows 7 - Add PHP Support greyed out

Tags: php, eclipse

I have Eclipse running on Windows 7, and am trying to work out how to get PHP support in my projects. Highlighting and intellisense seems to be working quite alright, but when I right-click my project and go to "Configure", the option "Add PHP Support" is grayed out.

Would anyone know how I could get that to be enabled, please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that's what you want to do? I just tested in my Eclipse install, and everything that is already a PHP project has that option greyed out. The only project I can choose that option on is a Java project.

If you create a project by File -> New -> PHP Project then you don't need to do anything else to enable PHP support.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm still trying to get a hold of Eclipse, and just saw a lot of people recommending ensuring that option was set.

Comment: I've never touched that setting and it's working OK for PHP for me :P If everything is sorted, can you mark the answer as accepted?